# Image not slide on pager dots click ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I'm working in ionic v5. I want to slide images on pager dots click, but it is not working now.

My code is:

```
 <ion-slides pager="true">
   <ion-slide>
     <p>Page1</p>
   </ion-slide>
   <ion-slide>
     <p>Page2</p>
   </ion-slide>
   <ion-slide>
     <p>Page3</p>
   </ion-slide>
 </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 5):

By default they are not clickable but, as you can see [in the Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#properties) you can set the `options` of the slider to change that:

> `options`: Options to pass to the swiper instance. See http://idangero.us/swiper/api/ for valid options

### Component

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "home.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["home.page.scss"]
})
export class HomePage {
  public items = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"];

  public sliderOptions = {
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      type: "bullets",
      clickable: true
    }
  };
}
```

### Template

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Home
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
  <p>
    Slider with clickable pager:
  </p>

  <ion-slides pager="true" [options]="sliderOptions">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of items">
      <p>{{ item }}</p>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Please take a look at this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-question-64318662?file=src/app/home/home.page.ts).

[image: demo project]